# creating a list with list comprehension with multiple statements

Tags: python, list, pdf, coding-efficiency

I am reading in a pdf file and appending its content to an empty list in a for loop. Whenever I look at this code it feels like it could be more efficient but in this case I'm not sure if I'm able to implement a list-comprehension. It does work like intended but my question is there a more efficient way of appending things to an empty list in a situation like this?

```
text = []

for count in range(countpage):
    pageObj=fileReader.getPage(count)
    t = pageObj.extractText()
    text.append(t)
```

Any input would be much appreciated

Comment: `text = [fileReader.getPage(count).extractText() for count in range(countpage)]`? You don't actually *need* the multiple statements; where you *do*, a list comprehension probably isn't the right thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you think a list comprehension makes it less readable in this case?

Comment: Possibly, but if you think so you can extract a function, e.g. `[getPageText(fileReader, count) for ...]`.

Comment: List comp seems fine if you use `i` instead of `count`. `countpage` is also a long variable and I generally dislike "count" or "num" or "number" in my var names. `text = [fileReader.getPage(i).extractText() for i in range(pages)]` is very sensible, I think.